# Identity Server4 using Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I wanna use Identity Server4 to manage user on my website with python.
I didn't found any useful resource.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have an IdentityServer up and running and you want to authenticate users/apps in a Python app? Do I have that right?

Comment: you are getting it right.

Comment: Is it a basic CLI script? Do you need a user to login? Or do you just want to call an API protected by a token issued by IdentityServer?

Comment: complete solution for managing users on my website.

Comment: You need to detail your usecase quite a bit. Do you have an existing system for user management? Why identity server? Why python? There are id solutions for python if you're not invested in dotnet, which might be easier.